# Async with a Timer

Tags: c#, asynchronous, timer

I'm updating my code to use Async, the issue is that to Timer.Elapsed requires a void return type, but this basically doesn't allow for an await, so the code doesn't wait and finishes too soon before everything is done.

Code:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
   Timer timer;

   timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
   timer.Interval = 3000;
   timer.Elapsed += OnTimerAsync;
   timer.Enabled = true;
   timer.Start();

   Console.WriteLine("Press the Enter key to exit the program... ");
   Console.ReadLine();
   Console.WriteLine("Terminating the application...");
}

public async static void OnTimerAsync(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs args)
{
   await ExecuteWorkflowAsync();
}

private async static Task<bool> ExecuteWorkflowAsync()
{
   List<Schedule> schedulesToRun;

   try
   {
      await JobLoader.LoadAsync(schedulesToRun);
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
       // Log ex
   }

  return true;
}
```

Is there a way to use the Timer object with Async?

Comment: What exactly is finishing too soon?

Comment: BTW, timer.Enabled = true; and timer.Start(); do the same thing.

Comment: It is unclear what you mean by "finishes too soon". Your code actually looks fine.

Comment: @Josh: Are you sure you need a timer? What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: LoadAync() has a process that kicks off jobs via async. It blocks until all jobs are finished.  But I find that each parent call has to implement async for the blocking to work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public async static void OnTimerAsync(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs args)
{
   timer.Enabled = false;
   await ExecuteWorkflowAsync();
   timer.Enabled = true;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it still didn't wait. I think I'm going to drop the timer and just use a Task.Delay in a loop to replace the timer.